# MYSQL merge in one column if given column has no value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I merge two column in ONE column if the given column (year_id) has no value (null)

table 1

```
id    txt      year_id      date
----------------------------------
1     text1      1
2     text2      2
3     text3      3
4     text4               2013-01-02
5     text5               2013-01-03
```

table 2

```
id    year     
----------------
1     2009     
2     2010      
3     2011     
4     2012
```

I need a result like this

```
id    txt      merge_column   
-------------------------
1     text1      2009
2     text2      2010
3     text3      2011
4     text4   2013-01-02
5     text5   2013-01-03
```

thank you in advance, this query complicates my mind.. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JOIN both table first the use `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()`.

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.txt,
        COALESCE(b.year, a.date) merge_column
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.year_id = b.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61ecf/1)

Comment: Nice this is awesome! this is what I wanted to see in my query... suberb!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, txt, IFNULL(date, year) merge_column
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.year_id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to convert the values to a common type.  I think string is the most likely.

```
select t1.id, t1.txt,
       coalesce(date_format(t2.date, '%y-%m-%d'), cast(t2.year as varchar(32))
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.year_id = t2.id
```